# Performing a boolean AND string search on sub-collections of a collection (non-LINQ)

Tags: c#

I hope the title makes sense.

I have a set of `items` that I want to search and select a subset of, based on a set of `keywords` that must all appear at least once in any of the `SubItems` of the `Item`s. I believe this could easily be achieved using LINQ, but I'm using .NET 2.0 for this project.

The code below should achieve pretty much what I want to do, assuming `AllBitsAreSet` is implemented, but I'm wondering if I'm missing an alternative, simpler way of doing this?

Since there doesn't appear to be a good way of checking if all the bits in a `BitArray` are set, besides looping through them all (please tell me if there is!), I'm wondering about "nicer" alternatives. Not necessarily more CPU efficient, because I doubt the below code will be too slow for the data sets I'm working with, but ones with less code.

```
public List<Item> Search(Item[] items, List<string> keywords)
{
    List<Item> results = new List<Item>();

    BitArray flags = new BitArray(keywords.Count);
    foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        flags.SetAll(false);
        foreach (SubItem subItem in item.SubItems)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Count; i++)
            {
                if (subItem.StringValue.IndexOf(keywords[i]) >= 0)
                    flags[i] = true;
            }
        }
        if (AllBitsAreSet(flags)) results.Add(item);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: How many subItems can an item have? The inner loop (for int i=0) looks like a problem to me.

Comment: It will be better if you provide sample input/expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LINQ Bridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to get LINQ support on .NET 2.0 and use the following LINQ query.

```
items.Where(i =>
    keywords.All(k =>
        i.SubItems.Any(s =>
            s.StringValue.Contains(k))));
```

You can avoid using the bit set if you swap the two inner loops - the performance impact depends on thenumber of sub items vs the number of keywords.

```
foreach (Item item in items)
{
    Boolean found = false;

    foreach (String keyword in keywords)
    {
        found = false;

        foreach (SubItem subItem in item.SubItems)
        {
            if (subItem.StringValue.Contains(keyword))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
        result.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as follows. Of course this is very similar to Daniel's solution, but I believe it is better.

```
    public List<Item> Search(Item[] items, List<string> keywords)
    {
        List<Item> results = new List<Item>();
        foreach (Item item in items)
            if(ContainsAllKeywords(item, keywords))
                results.Add(item);
        return results;
    }

    bool ContainsAllKeywords(Item item, List<string> keywords)
    {
        foreach (string keyword in keywords)
            if (!ContainsKey(item.SubItems, keyword))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    bool ContainsKey(IEnumerable<SubItem> subItems, string key)
    {
        foreach (SubItem subItem in subItems)
            if (subItem.StringValue.Contains(key))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

**edit:** changed `==` to `.Contains()` as per comment

Comment: Your code does not have the same functionality as Blixt's and Daniel's. Your code checks for an exact match between subItem.StringValue and each keyword. It should be checking for a substring match.

Comment: If an exact match was permitted then much better optimisations would be available. For example, you could store the keywords as keys in a Dictionary (or use a HashSet in later versions of .NET) which would give O(1) lookup time.

Comment: Luke, yes that was a mistake it should have been .Contains() instead of ==. Thanks for catching that! I have edited the code. However, I do not agree with your assessment about using a dictionary/hash. I understand that hash lookup is O(1), but I don't see how that can be directly applied to improve performance in this situation. Could you please provide a code sample? Thanks for the comments.